# Elegant way determine last observation among timepoints?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

To start, here's some example data called df1:

```
ID Time      Score1 Score2 SumScore
1  Baseline  1      2      3
1  Midpoint  2      2      4
1  Final     3      2      5
2  Baseline  2      2      4
2  Midpoint  5      2      7
2  Final     6      2      8
```

I should mention now that some of my 'Final' timepoint scores in these data are missing. I am interested in only those observations with missing Final timepoints. Let's select these observations an call the new df df2: `df2<-df1%>%filter(is.na(SumScore)==T,Time=="Final")`

From here, I spread the data using `tidyr::spread()` to create a new data frame (df3)that looks like this:

```
df3<-spread(df,ID,SumScore)

ID Baseline Midpoint 
1  3        NA       
1  NA       4        
1  NA       NA       
2  4        NA       
2  NA       7        
2  NA       NA
```

What I would like to accomplish is to determine the last observation (among the baseline and midpoint timepoints) and then carry that observation forward for the observations in df1 that are missing the Final timepoint score. It is possible that for some observations, the midpoint scores are missing as well.

Thanks

Comment: Please include your desired output for the toy example in your question.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1, df1$ID), function(a) a[NROW(a),]))`

Comment: @d.b This seems to work really well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, something like this might be what you are looking for...

```
df4 <- df1 %>% select(-c(Score1,Score2)) %>% 
               spread(key=Time,value=SumScore) %>%
               mutate(finalScore=coalesce(Final,Midpoint,Baseline))


df4
  ID Baseline Final Midpoint finalScore
1  1        3     5        4          5
2  2        4     8        7          8
```